# How to search on a particular property with multiple values in Azure AD SDK java

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

I have implemented the following code to get the user for a single upn value. In the below code in the searchCriteria i get the value as "avinash@upn.com" and it returns the user object that matches the upn.

```
@Override
    public AzureResponse getUsersByUPN(Map<String, String> credentials, String searchCriteria) {

        log.debug("in getUserByUPN()    :start...");
        validateToken(credentials);
        List<Option> requestOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
        requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "startswith(userPrincipalName,'" + searchCriteria + "')"));

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        AzureResponse response = new AzureResponse();
        try {
            UserCollectionRequestBuilder usersClientBuilder = graphClient.users();
            UserCollectionRequest usersRequest = usersClientBuilder.buildRequest(requestOptions);
            do {
                UserCollectionPage userCollectionPage = usersRequest.get();
                users.addAll(userCollectionPage.getCurrentPage());
                usersClientBuilder = userCollectionPage.getNextPage();
                if (usersClientBuilder == null) {
                    usersRequest = null;
                } else {
                    usersRequest = usersClientBuilder.buildRequest();
                }
            } while (usersRequest != null);
            response.setData(users);

        } catch (GraphServiceException e) {
            log.error("GraphServiceException occurred in getUserByUPN() : ", e);
            setErrorResponse(response, e.getResponseCode(), e.getResponseMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occurred in getUserByUPN() : ", e);
            setErrorResponse(response, 400, e.getMessage());
        }
        log.debug("in getUserByUPN()    :end.");
        return response;
    }
```

Now i get a List of upn and i want to get all the user objects of those upn's. Is that possible through the above.

For ex : I have a list of upn's like below

```
List<String> upns = Arrays.asList('avinash@upn.com','kishore@upn.com')
Can i pass this list directly to the QueryOption

List<Option> requestOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
            requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "startswith(userPrincipalName,'" + upns + "')"));
```

Can we query on the list directly or do we need to iterate on the list and pass each upn and get the user object

I have gone through the below link, but could not figure out

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=java

Any help/suggestions please